# How to use regex to match substring via group repeatedly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

For example, I have a string:

```
var s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
```

I would like to get an array of substrings whose length is 1 to 5.

The result I expect is:

```
["ABCDE", "FGHIJ", "KLMN"]
```

I tried to get the result via regexp.
Here is my code:

```
var s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var result = s.match(/(.{1,5})+/)
```

But I can only get the last match of the group instead of all of them:

```
result[1];
"KLMN"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "g" to the end of the pattern:

```js
var s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var result = s.match(/.{1,5}/g)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` with a capturing group, and remove the empty strings:

```js
var s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var result = s.split(/(.{1,5})/).filter(e => e);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Didn't know split() function can accept regexp as argument. Thanks!

Comment: No problem @krave, always glad to help.